# Unrecognized Selector Sent To Instance [UIView setRefreshControl:]

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, storyboard

The app using custom refresh control in multiple VCs. However, only one of them not working and throwing the subject error.

Custom UIRefreshControl:

```
class CustRefreshCont: UIRefreshControl {

     override init() {
        super.init()

        let noColor = UIColor.clear
        let lightGrayColor = UIColor.lightGray
        self.tintColor = lightGrayColor
        self.backgroundColor = noColor
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I checked the code in other VCs, nothing seems different. I assume the error is fixable at MainStoryboard somehow (ie at Inspector of a UIView?)

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Provided additional code:

Decleration:

```
let refreshControl = CustRefreshCont()
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PortfolioVC.refreshData), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)

// if it is iOS 10 and higher run new method
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
} else {
    tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
}
```

Function:

```
@objc private func refreshData (){
    // Calculate elapsedTime
    elapsedTime = Date().timeIntervalSince(lastRefresh)
    convToInt = refreshRestrictSec - NSInteger(elapsedTime)

    // If last refresh call was older then a minute
    if  NSInteger(elapsedTime) > refreshRestrictSec {

        // Displaying text while updating
        self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Updating data...", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.lightGray, NSAttributedStringKey.backgroundColor : UIColor.clear])
        print(elapsedTime)
        view.endEditing(true)
        selectedCurrencies.removeAll()

        // Pulling JSON data and updating selected Currencies
        downloadCurrencies(completion: { (isComp, isErr) in
            if Currencies.count > 0 {
                syncValuesAtStored(cur: selectedCurrencies)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    calculateTotalWorth()
                    excludeNonePosses()
                    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
                    animateTableView(tableView: self.tableView)
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    lastRefresh = Date()
                }
            } else {
                print("Error on Refresh")
            }
        })

    } else {
        print(elapsedTime)
        self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "You can refresh \(convToInt) seconds later!", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.lightGray, NSAttributedStringKey.backgroundColor : UIColor.clear])
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is telling you that a plain `UIView` doesn't have a `refreshControl` property, which seem correct.  What is happening in the code where you get this error?  (i.e. How are you using your subclass?)

Comment: Hello Philip, I edited the question via additional code related. When app crashes it shows the AppDelegate. Not showing a line of code I entered. Thank you.

Comment: When you do this `tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl`, can you verify what `tableView` actually is either by printing or examining in the debugger?  If it's a table view controller, check what its `view` property is also.

Comment: Hi Philip, after playing around I finally fixed the issue put the answer below. Thank you so much for helping with it. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

After deleting and re-connecting outlet of tableView from related VC (PortfolioVC) on MainStoryboard fixed the error. Therefore, this must be a bug of xCode.